# Create a List with an array of custom classes in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, combine

I tried creating a list of custom classes in SwiftUI, but keep having problems with the UI updates. I made my class conform to `BindableObject` and it calls the `didChange.send()` function correctly when a property changes, but the change doesn't seem to get passed through to the array, as the view does not update, when I change a property of my custom class in the array.

Here is a basic example of what I mean:

```swift
class Media: BindableObject, Identifiable {
    typealias PublisherType = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
    var didChange = PublisherType()

    var id: Int {
        didSet {
            didChange.send()
        }
    }
    var name: String {
        didSet {
            print("Name changed from \(oldValue) to \(self.name)")
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var media = [
        Media(id: 0, name: "Name 0"),
        Media(id: 1, name: "Name 1"),
        Media(id: 2, name: "Name 2"),
        Media(id: 3, name: "Name 3"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(media) { media in
                Text(media.name)
            }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.media.first!.name = "Name \(Int.random(in: 100...199))"
                }) {
                    Text("Change")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.media.append(Media(id: 4, name: "Name 4"))
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When pressing the "Change" button, it just changes the name of the first media object in the array, which does not result in a re-rendering of the view. When I press the "Add" button, he adds an object to the array, therefore re-rendering the UI and also displaying the changed name of the first object (from pressing "Change").

Now my question is, if there is a way to link the publisher of `Media` to the publisher of `Array<Media>`, so that when the `Media` Publisher fires, the `Array<Media>` Publisher fires too and therefore causes the view to re-render.

When I move the `Text(media.name)` in a separate view (which holds the media as a `@State` property, it works as intended, as the subview itself request the re-render.

But assuming I don't want to use a custom view but just a simple `Text` view, is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are mixing two separate things. @State is meant to be used for anything internal to the view. While @BindableObject, is meant to hold something external to the view (i.e., your data model). When you define a @BindableObject, you do not reference it with @State, but with @ObjectBinding.

I don't know what was the case, but if you intend to use @State, the implementation should have been like this:

```swift
struct Media {

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var media = [
        Media(id: 0, name: "Name 0"),
        Media(id: 1, name: "Name 1"),
        Media(id: 2, name: "Name 2"),
        Media(id: 3, name: "Name 3"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(media.identified(by: \.id)) { media in
                Text(media.name)
            }

            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.media[0].name = "Name \(Int.random(in: 100...199))"
                }) {
                    Text("Change")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.media.append(Media(id: 4, name: "Name 4"))
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You would mostly use @State for some internal state of the view, but also while prototyping. What was your intention with the Media object?

---

### UPDATE

To implement it with a @ObjectBinding:

Supposing you are instantiating your CustomView in the SceneDelegate, you need to pass it the library:

```swift
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {

            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

            let library = MediaLibrary(store: [Media(id: 0, name: "Name 0"),
            Media(id: 1, name: "Name 1"),
            Media(id: 2, name: "Name 2"),
            Media(id: 3, name: "Name 3")])

            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView(library: library))
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

And the implementation:

```
struct Media {
    let id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

class MediaLibrary: BindableObject {
    typealias PublisherType = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>
    var didChange = PublisherType()

    var store: [Media] {
        didSet {
            didChange.send()
        }
    }

    init(store: [Media]) {
        self.store = store
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @ObjectBinding var library: MediaLibrary

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.library.store.identified(by: \.id)) { media in
                Text(media.name)
            }
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.library.store[0].name = "Name \(Int.random(in: 100...199))"
                }) {
                    Text("Change")
                }
                Button(action: {
                    self.library.store.append(Media(id: 4, name: "Name 4"))
                }) {
                    Text("Add")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I wanted to have a `List` showing many complex `Media` objects and I wanted the list to refresh when I changed a property of the media objects (because the name gets loaded after the view appeared via a network call). Using `@ObjectBinding` only works with my `Media` class directly, because the Array doesn't conform to `BindableObject`.
In my project Media is a bigger class that has properties, which get loaded from API calls and therefore are not directly available, so the List has to refresh after they loaded.

Comment: Ok, I updated so that the data resides outside the view. In that case, as explained in the WWDC session 226 (Data Flow Through SwiftUI), you need to instantiate the view, by passing the model as an argument.

Comment: You now can make all your network calls and update the library. The List will update without any extra work.

Comment: Well yes, your solutions works, but only because `Media` is a `struct` now and therefore it always gets replaced when a property changes. When I make `Media` a class your solution doesn't work anymore. Sadly in my case, `Media` needs to be a class because other classes inherit from it. I really hoped there were some kind of solution where you could just "link" the publisher of `Media` with the Array (e.g. that the Array subscribes to the `Media` objects and passes the events through to the View).

Comment: Then simply add immediately after updating the name a call to self.library.didChange.send().

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the magic that makes it work with structs, is the new Key Path Member Lookup (Swift Evolution: SE-0252). Check session 415 (Modern Swift API Design).

Comment: Yes I suppose that would work. Not the solution I hoped for, but better than nothing. I will also look into the Key Path Member Lookup.